# How to get number of particular name in sqlite table by query

Tags: java, android, sqlite, select, datatable

I have a table in which name and number of people are stored.  Now I want to make a method in sqlite helper class which will return the number of particular person whose name I will pass in the method

There is something wrong with my code.

Here is my code

```
public String fetchGroup(SQLiteDatabase inDatabase,  String valueCheck){

    String query = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groupname='" + valueCheck;

    Cursor  cursor = inDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
    String place = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("contactid"));
       return place;
```

Comment: You did not append the closing single quote: `String query = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groupname='" + valueCheck + "'";` But check this way: `String query = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groupname=?"; Cursor  cursor = inDatabase.rawQuery(query,new String[] {valueCheck});`

Comment: Refer this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take care to use `cursor.moveToFirst()` command before reading datas

Else, instead counting the number of people in Java, you can just modify your query to have only this number return.

Something like this :

```
public String fetchGroup(SQLiteDatabase inDatabase,  String valueCheck){

    String query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM groups WHERE groupname=\"" + valueCheck + "\"";

    Cursor  cursor = inDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int place = cursor.getInt(0);
    return String.valueOf(place);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After your query do

```
 int count = 0;
 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // increment variable
    count++;
}
```

after iterating you will get number of count